# Using Three.js to put a pin on a map of the USA

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to figure out a way to use latitude and longitude to put a pin on a map of the USA.

I'm using a perspective camera btw.

This is my mesh, which basically adds a color map, and a displacement map to give it some height:

```
const mapMaterial = new MeshStandardMaterial({
    map: colorTexture,
    displacementMap: this.app.textures[displacementMap],
    metalness: 0,
    roughness: 1,
    displacementScale: 3,
    color: 0xffffff,
    //wireframe: true
})

const mapTextureWidth = 100
const mapTextureHeight = 100

const planeGeom = new PlaneGeometry(mapTextureWidth, mapTextureHeight, mapTextureWidth - 1, mapTextureHeight - 1)

this.mapLayer = new Mesh(planeGeom, mapMaterial)
this.mapLayer.rotation.x = -1
this.mapLayer.position.set(0, 0, 0); // set the original position
```

I've also added a camera to give it a slight tilt so we can see the height in the mountains and such.

In the end it looks like this:
[image: USA map]

What I need to do is add a map pin on the map by using latitude and longitude.

I've played around with converting lat and long to pixels, but that gives me an x and y relative to the screen, and not the map itself, *(found this in a different SO post)*:

```
convertGeoToPixelPosition(
    latitude, longitude,
    mapWidth , // in pixels
    mapHeight , // in pixels
    mapLonLeft , // in degrees
    mapLonDelta , // in degrees (mapLonRight - mapLonLeft);
    mapLatBottom , // in degrees
    mapLatBottomDegree
) {
    const x = (longitude - mapLonLeft) * (mapWidth / mapLonDelta);

    latitude = latitude * Math.PI / 180
    const worldMapWidth = ((mapWidth / mapLonDelta) * 360) / (2 * Math.PI)
    const mapOffsetY = (worldMapWidth / 2 * Math.log((1 + Math.sin(mapLatBottomDegree)) / (1 - Math.sin(mapLatBottomDegree))))
    const y = mapHeight - ((worldMapWidth / 2 * Math.log((1 + Math.sin(latitude)) / (1 - Math.sin(latitude)))) - mapOffsetY)

    return { "x": x , "y": y}
}
```

Any thoughts on how I can transform the latitude and longitude to world coordinates?

I've already created the sprite for the map pin, and adding them works great, just have to figure out the proper place to put them....

Comment: If you add the marker as a child of the map plane, your position will position the marker in map space.. so the x and y will range to whatever you PlaneGeometry(width,height is.

Comment: @manthrax the width and height are 100, and the result of the convertGeo is `{x: 747.3069617760459, y: 2233.3042336255235}`, as the image is 4096x4096, so that wouldn't work

Comment: Are you limited to only the map of the USA? Could it be a map of another country?

Comment: @pailhead The USA to start. There will be others as well, just starting with the USA.

Comment: My advice would be to think in more generic terms and not limit yourself to writing code that would deal only with the USA. Make something that deals with a "map" :)

Answer (score 0):

Add your marker as a child of the mapLayer...

this.mapLayer.add( marker )

then set its position:

marker.position.set( (x/4096)-0.5)*100, (y/4096)-0.5)*100, 0)

where x and y are what you get from your convertGeo function.

Comment: Noice! very close, they are a little off though, the y coordinates seem to not ever go into the negative, but the x coordinates are almost spot on.

Comment: is it maybe something as simple as:
x = latitude*100/180
y = longitude*100/90
?